# How many cities around the world has been successfully applied the ISO 37120 standard?

Tags: parties, political-system, policy, geopolitics, citizenship

How many cities around the world has been successfully applied, True social changes, political changes, economic changes and changes in education, Improving Quality of Life and Social Welfare under the ISO 37120 standard?
Portals in different cities around the world show called Smart Cities saying and working under ISO 37120 however the media and its data released by international and impartial agencies say otherwise. That cities are really Smart Cities and meet the standard 37120?

Comment: [This site](http://cityminded.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Patricia_McCarney_PDF.pdf) may be helpful. In Europe London, Barcelona, Amsterdam, Rotterdam and Helsinki were "foundation cities". In North America - Boston and Toronto.